# Python: end execution in while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

we are beginners and want to code the game Mastermind in Python. (Please see our code below.)
Problem:
We want to end the execution of the code if the 'StopIteration' error occurs in the 'while' loop. But somehow 'quit()' doesn't work in this place. Can anyone give us a clue how to solve this problem?

```
def inconsistent(new_guess, guesses):
   for guess in guesses:
      res = check(guess[0], new_guess)
      (rightly_positioned, right_colour) = guess[1]
      if res != [rightly_positioned, right_colour]:
         return True # inconsistent
   return False # i.e. consistent

while inconsistent (new_guess, guesses):
        try:
            new_guess=next(generator)
        except StopIteration:
            print("Error: Your answers were inconsistent!")
            break
```

Comment: You could do `sys.exit()`, but usually I would rather write a `main` function that is called in the program, and I just have to `return` to end execution. If your `while` is not followed by any code, your `break` is also enough.

Answer (score 0):

Break should work. If you want to skip this guess you could use

```
continue
```